# Buenas tardes, tengo un problema con el tema de la hamburguesa que se adapta a celular de Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

```
    <header>   **header de la hamburguesa**
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">中央</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                  <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="../menu.html">INICIO</a>
                  <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="../paginas/institucional.html">INSTITUCIONES</a>
                  <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="../paginas/Seguridad.html">SEGURIDAD</a>
                  <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="../paginas/medioambiente.html">MEDIO AMBIENTE</a>
                  <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="../paginas/busquedaslaborales.html">BUSQUEDAS LABORALES</a>
        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

no tiene style por ahora, el problema que tiene el codigo es que todo bien hasta que al cambiar a la version mobile, donde se tiene que ver la hamburguesa, esta no se deja abrir. Es decir, no tiene nada, siendo que lo copio tal cual de bootstrap :C

Comment: a mi me funciona bien, fíjate si importaste bien los cdn de la pagina oficial de bootstrap 5, tanto el css como el js. Son 2 una etiqueta <link> y una etiqueta <script> dentro de tu <head>

Comment: Seguramente te esté faltando incorporar el js de Bootstrap. Sin el no te funciona el collapse ni los dropdown, etc.. Ya que es js que controla los comportamientos..

Answer (score 0):

Falta incorporar el js de Bootstrap.

Deberías añadir esto:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Justo antes de la etiqueta de cierre del body.